# Registering the same ETW TraceLogging Provider GUID from multiple processes and within the same process

Tags: c++, windows, events, trace, etw

From [TraceLogging documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/traceloggingprovider/nf-traceloggingprovider-traceloggingregisterex#remarks):

> If you attempt to register a provider that is already registered, the registration will fail.

It's unclear whether 'provider' refers to the GUID or the object represented by `hProvider`. Can anyone confirm if it's a valid operation to register the same GUID from
1. multiple processes
2. multiple modules (DLLs/EXE) in the same process
3. within the same module ?

I've tried {1} and {2} and they've been working - I can get events from both the processes/modules. Just need to make sure that this is expected behavior.

Comment: I am also interested in it.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it refers to **handle** object itself.

`The scope of a TraceLogging provider handle is strictly limited to the module (the DLL or EXE) in which it is defined. The provider handle from one module must not be shared with code in other modules. In other words, for any handle g_hProvider, all instances of TraceLoggingWrite(g_hProvider, ...) must reside in the same EXE or DLL as the TRACELOGGING_DEFINE_PROVIDER(g_hProvider, ...) definition. If this rule is not followed, the behavior of TraceLoggingWrite is unpredictable, especially regarding the way it handles event IDs (e.g. event ID collisions are likely).`

a comment in `TraceLoggingProvider.h`

Answer (score 1):

In this documentation, the "provider" refers to the `hProvider` defined with `TRACELOGGING_DEFINE_PROVIDER`.

It is valid to have multiple "provider" variables that use the same GUID. You can have multiple processes that each register the same provider, or multiple DLLs in the same process, or even multiple distinct `TRACELOGGING_DEFINE_PROVIDER` (with different variable names for each one). Each of them is an independent provider handle that can be registered and unregistered separately.

Obviously it's more efficient to not have multiple variables that do the same thing, so you don't want to have multiple duplicate variables in the same DLL if you can avoid it.

One additional note is that the GUID is a kind of contract. All of the events with the same GUID should have the same provider name and should have the same definitions for keywords. The reason for sharing the same GUID should be to allow the events to all be turned on/off together. When that makes sense, share the GUID. If that doesn't make sense (if the events don't work together), consider picking a new GUID and new provider name for the new group of events.